# Importing text file inside of DataGridView , C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataview

I have a problem , on button click , dataview should get all data from text file.
I dont understand why it doesnt work .
I have another function to put data inside of the text file , that works.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance
[This is code of the function which should get all data and put them into the dataviewgrid when I run the program, but there is some problem , I dont get error messages at all , but its not happening .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sStnj.jpg) 
[This is code which works really good , it showing all columns and all data will be in text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY8Kg.jpg)
[filling data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqwlP.jpg)
[data which I got in txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwoWq.jpg)

```
    private void dodajToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 //upis u datoteku
 using (TextWriter smesti = new StreamWriter("podaci.txt")) {
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
  if (!dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
      smesti.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
      if (j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) {
        smesti.Write("|");
      }
    }
    smesti.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

}
}

```
private void Admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
        tabela.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        tabela.Columns.Add("Naziv", typeof(string));
        tabela.Columns.Add("Zanr", typeof(string));
        tabela.Columns.Add("Duzina", typeof(int));
        tabela.Columns.Add("Granica godina: ", typeof(int));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;
        
       
        

    }
   
    private void ucitaj()
    {
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
        string[] tekst = File.ReadAllLines("podaci.txt");
        string[] vrednosti;

        for (int i = 0; i < tekst.Length; i++)
        {
            vrednosti = tekst[i].ToString().Split('|');
            string[] red = new string[vrednosti.Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < vrednosti.Length; j++)
            {
                red[j] = vrednosti[j].Trim();
            }
            tabela.Rows.Add(red);
        }
        
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucitaj();
    }
```

Comment: And one more thing , how I can setup primary key for ID column? :)

Comment: Please edit your question to show your actual code, not an image of it

Comment: Okay done , I added code

Comment: Is there some reason the code writes to the file using a `Tab` and “|” (Bar) character as a delimiter for each field `+"\t"+"|"`, then, when the code reads the file, it appears to split the fields on the “/” forward slash character …`.Split('/');`? This obviously will not work. In addition, when writing the file, the code never, puts each “row” on a separate line. This will create ONE (1) line of data in the text file. Therefore, you will not know which data goes to which row. Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: That "|" is used just to organize better data .

Comment: I tried to delete that and I tried again to run program , the problem which I am getting when I click button is System.ArgumentException: 'Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.'

Comment: The error is coming from the fact that the file you are reading only has ONE (1) line it. In the `dodajToolStripMenuItem_Click` event, there should be a `smesti.WriteLine()`… after the second `for` loop to write each grid row to a “LINE” in the file… so if there are 10 rows in the grid, then the file will have ten lines. This is causing the error since the array is larger than the number of columns in the table.

Comment: I changed it but I am still getting same error

Comment: The posted code looks the same to me. What did you change?

Comment: Okay I changed it now here , but I am still getting same mistake

Comment: When I open text file , I dont see value of last column , maybe because of that is error?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to write the grid data to the file. The code simply writes each cell to the file, then it writes a Bar “|” delimiter unless the cell is the last cell on the row. We do not want a delimiter at the end of the line.

```
private void dodajToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //upis u datoteku
  using (TextWriter smesti = new StreamWriter("podaci.txt")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
      if (!dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
          smesti.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
          if (j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) {
            smesti.Write("|");
          }
        }
        smesti.WriteLine();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the code that reads the file....

```
DataTable tabela;

private void ucitaj() {
  //DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
  tabela.Rows.Clear();
  string[] tekst = File.ReadAllLines("podaci.txt");
  string[] vrednosti;

  for (int i = 0; i < tekst.Length; i++) {
    vrednosti = tekst[i].ToString().Split('|');
    string[] red = new string[vrednosti.Length];
    for (int j = 0; j < vrednosti.Length; j++) {
      red[j] = vrednosti[j].Trim();
    }
    tabela.Rows.Add(red);
  }
  dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;
}
```

AND... you need to move the `DataTable` ... `tabela` to be a global variable. SO make `tabela` global...

```
DataTable tabela;
```

Then in the `Load` event, change the line...

```
DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
```

To...

```
tabela = new DataTable();
```

Comment: Okay I changed code and program will put data in text file , but same error when I am trying to import that text file to read this. I changed this code but its same error .

Comment: Last column(Granice godina) on datagridview , I still didnt  get in text file what is really strange

Comment: edit your question with the updated code that reads the file.

Comment: Why program cant read and remember last colum(Granice godina) in text file , maybe because of that cant load when I run button?

Comment: I can only guess you may be looking at the wrong `podaci.txt` file. In my tests, using the posted code, the last column is saved as expected. Can you confirm you are looking at the right file?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that I am looking at the right file , do you have teamviewer or anydesk so you can check it out ? :)

Comment: How are you confining this? Did you make changes to the grid and see those changes reflected in the file after saving? I am just saying the posted code works in my tests. Your code is either different or your looking at the wrong file.

Comment: I found out what was the problem